# jqGrid adding 'Data Verification' row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that I'm filling with data from a stored procedure. I get the desired results returned from the proc, but it is adding a 'Data Verification' row on the front end. I can't figure out where it is getting this from. It also adds the row (see the ID) 3 times, and is pulling a different Location somehow.

The odd part is it only seems to happen on the records that are Dev Tx Specialist in the Delivered By column.[image: This is the jqGrid]

[image: Stored Procedure results]

I've got other grids set up the same way in the application, and they're working fine. Has anyone seen this before?

```
function GetGridData() {
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: 'ServiceDelivery.aspx/GetIFSPDetails',
    mtype: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['ID', 'Service', 'Location', 'Delivered By', 'Frequency', 'Per', 'Hrs', 'Start', 'End', 'Initials'],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'IFSPDetailId', index: 'IFSPDetailID', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 50, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'Service', index: 'Service', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 90, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'ServiceLocation', index: 'ServiceLocation', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 60, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'DeliveredBy', index: 'DeliveredBy', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 150, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'Frequency', index: 'Frequency', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 70, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'Per', index: 'Per', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 40, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'Duration', index: 'Duration', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 50, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
               { name: 'StartDate', index: 'StartDate', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 70, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'n/j/Y' } },
               { name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 70, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'n/j/Y' } },
               { name: 'Initials', index: 'Initials', key: true, search: false, hidden: false, width: 50, align: "left", editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },

    ],
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {

        if (_typeChanged) {
            postData.page = 1;
            _typeChanged = false;
        }


        if (postData.searchField == null) {
            postData.searchField = "";
            postData._search = false;
            postData.searchOper = "";
            postData.searchString = "";
            postData.serviceDate = $$('txtServiceDate').val();
            postData.caseId = vm.caseId();
        }

        return JSON.stringify(postData);

    },
    jsonReader: {
        id: "IFSPDetailId",

        root: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != "") {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.rows;
            }
        },
        page: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != "") {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.page;
            }
        }, total: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != "") {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.total;
            }
        }, records: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != "") {
                var x = $.parseJSON(obj.d);
                return x.rows.length;
            }
        }, repeatitems: false

    },
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {

    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {

    },
    loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
        alert("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    },
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50, 100, 150, 200],
    sortname: '',
    sortorder: "",
    modal: true,
    viewrecords: false,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    caption: '',
    loadonce: true,
    width: 770,
    height: 300,
    editurl: '',
    grouping: false,
    footerrow: false,
    hoverrows: false,
    grouping: false,
    footerrow: false,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    onSelectRow: function () {
        $('#divIFSPDetailModal').dialog("close");
        getSelectedRowData('ifsp');
    }
}).navGrid("#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false, view: false })}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you ask. Do you want to remove 'Data Verification' row and you can't do that on the server side? Is your question: how to filter the data before displaying? You direct question "Has anyone seen this before?" is too unspecific. Please include additionally the information about the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's would be good if you include the demo or JavaScript code, which you use.

Comment: Yes, the jqGrid is adding the Data Verification row on the front end. When I break the code it is receiving the correct data as well, but for some reason when it is being displayed, the Data Verification row is added, along with a second non-existent row below it. There is only 1 ID of 315663, and as you can see it's showing 3. jqGrid v4.5.2 free jqGrid.

Comment: I can't do that on the server side, because it doesn't exist in the returned object on the server side. It isn't there until it is being serialized at some point on the client side.

Comment: "free jqGrid" and "Guriddo jqGrid JS" are names of products, which are both based on old "jqGrid" product. You use retro version 4.5.2 (4.5 years old) of "jqGrid" (not "free jqGrid"). One clear bug in your code one can see in `colModel`. You use `key: true` in **all columns**. It's wrong. One can use `key: true` maximal for **one** column, which have to contain *different* (unique) values, which can be used as rowids. I suppose that the property should be only in `IFSPDetailId` column.

Comment: Ohhhh, I didn't even notice that!!! I copied and pasted and didn't remove the key attribute! I'll give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! If removing of `key: true` not solves the problem then it would be good if you include test JSON data return from the server, which can be used to reproduce the problem.